# Run a variable as a statement (command) in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

How to make a variable run as a procedure in Fortran?

In bat/cmd i can set:

```
if “%_some_var%” == “some_value” (

     set _var=exit /b

      ) else (

      set _var=Call :_label

     )
```

Along the execution of a bat, the variable will receive a value according to its behavior during the run. This value will be assinged to a statement or command, then in bat, I´ll be able to run this variable as a statement/command.

```
!_var!
```

How can I do the same in Fortran?

Comment: I have only seen this feature in interpreting languages (feel free to correct me). Fortran requires compiling.

Comment: @ WeijunZhou, thank you for comment, the idea is to find a way for the compiler to skip debugging/compiling instructions which are usually checked, so in other words to find a way to force  compiling.

Comment: Sounds like a [xy problem]. Could you provide more information on your problem? Maybe you could use preprocessor instructions.

Comment: The simple answer is **"This is not possible."** If you tell us what you want to actually achieve, we might be able to tell you something more useful.

Comment: @Vladimir F, thank you for your comment, but can you please elaborate your answer why *This is not possible*?

Comment: _Run a variable as a statement in Fortran_ <- **this is not possible**. There is no such concept in the language nor constructs or syntax to do that. The point is: maybe your don't even need it

Comment: *Some* (mainly scripting) languages supply something like [tag:eval] (`eval()`), which evaluates a string as an expression of that language at run-time. Classical compiled languages like Fortran, C, C++, Pascal and many others do NOT have anything like that.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is writing the text on a file, invoking a command to compile it (of course, if the compiler is available on the running platform) then call the result program and pray to God it works and isn't random malicious stuff that will throw world war III

Comment: Well one could even compile it as dynamic library, load it at runtime and just call the subprogram, but one should **very well** think before, whether it is the right thing to do. Most often it is not.

Comment: Or for the very brave ones compile to machine code and put it at the right place in the stack or other part of memory and call it. Do not try at home, it will most likely not work.